# Why oldest trees are all around 4k years old?

Tags: trees

In christianity stackexchange I saw someone discussing young earth creationism.

One of the evidence they show is that the oldest tree, if measured by ring counts, are around 4k years.

Which, according to YEC, correspond to the Noah's flood.

Yes there are trees that are 10k years old. However, YEC doesn't believe in carbon dating. I wonder what ring counts do those tree have.

Is there any other reasonable explanation why oldest trees are 4k years old besides some massive catastrophe to all trees 4k years ago?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Tjikko).

Comment: Actually,   the oldest trees  are  almost 5000  years old. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oldest_trees)

Comment: You could argue on the same grounds that the world is only 200 years old. After all, there are no 200 year old people! What they are missing is that trees have natural lifespans too.

Comment: You can also use dendrochronology, matching ring patterns in the oldest parts of living wood to dead wood to extend the record back past 10,000 years: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrochronology  Also, if those old trees are supposed to have been around "forever", why do they produce seeds?